# how to remove advertisement opencart in admin panel

Tags: opencart

1. How to remove `OpenCart © 2009-2019 All Rights Reserved. Version 3.0.3.2.` in admin panel dashboard? Opencart advertisement all admin dashboard. log in before & log in after all advertisement opencart.
2. Force Login to View Products/Store. As soon as the customer came to our website, and after some time duration, force login the register. Like in the pintreast website without extension.

I am using opencart 3.0.3.2

Answer (score -1):

**Very simple solutions:**

Go to `admin\language\en-gb\common\footer.php`

Find

```
$_['text_footer']  = '<a href="http://www.opencart.com">OpenCart</a> &copy; 2009-' . date('Y') . ' All Rights Reserved.';
$_['text_version'] = 'Version %s';
```

Replace with

```
$_['text_footer']  = '';
$_['text_version'] = '';
```

Comment: I have removed the vote-begging messages from your material before. On this occasion, I have helpfully downvoted, in order to remind you that this material does not belong in posts.